# Whether to use Disqus or implement a commenting system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, disqus, comments

I have a simple asp.net mvc 5 site with its own authentication system. Users can sign in either using my site's account or from external such as facebook or google, etc... I want to add a commenting system to allow users feedback on the site's content.

I have tried using Disqus by embedding its universal code script snippet and things seem to work fine. However, the problem is that Disqus requires users to log in again via its own authentication. If users have signed in to my site, I don't want users to do that again just to leave comments. After some searching around I concluded that Disqus was not really what I need and decided not to use it.

Now I am trying to determine whether there's a commenting system that'd be easy to integrate to my site or if I should just implement my own. I don't care too much about nested comments, if it's supported then better but otherwise no big deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a solution to your problem, and that is single sign-on which is a disqus feature offered for free.

More info - http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/684744-getting-started-with-single-sign-on

Comment: I don't think this is what I wanted. I was aware of the SSO option, however my site already has a nice and simple signon support. What I would consider a solution is having Disqus use my site's authentication instead of its own.

Comment: Yes this is what Disqus offers - integration into your own authentication mechanism

Comment: @user1715925 Disqus SSO does allow you to authenticate "remote" Disqus users with your site's user authentication method. The SSO code is placed on your site, and sends the user payload to Disqus and logs them in to Disqus for your site only. The link posted above will explain in more detail.

Comment: Yep, you definitely want to use Single Sign-On. You can even find a C# example to create the SSO payload here: https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/sso/cs/DisqusSSO.cs

Comment: Thanks. I missed this when I was skimming through their website.